# Why does this Haskell code typecheck with fundeps but produce an untouchable error with type families?

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, type-families

Given some type definitions:

```
data A
data B (f :: * -> *)
data X (k :: *)
```

…and this typeclass:

```
class C k a | k -> a
```

…these (highly contrived for the purposes of a minimal example) function definitions typecheck:

```
f :: forall f. (forall k. (C k (B f)) => f k) -> A
f _ = undefined

g :: (forall k. (C k (B X)) => X k) -> A
g = f
```

However, if we use a type family instead of a class with a functional dependency:

```
type family F (k :: *)
```

…then the equivalent function definitions fail to typecheck:

```
f :: forall f. (forall k. (F k ~ B f) => f k) -> A
f _ = undefined

g :: (forall k. (F k ~ B X) => X k) -> A
g = f
```

```
• Couldn't match type ‘f0’ with ‘X’
    ‘f0’ is untouchable
      inside the constraints: F k ~ B f0
      bound by a type expected by the context:
                 F k ~ B f0 => f0 k
  Expected type: f0 k
    Actual type: X k
• In the expression: f
  In an equation for ‘g’: g = f
```

I read Section 5.2 of [the OutsideIn(X) paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/outsideinx-modular-type-inference-with-local-assumptions/), which describes touchable and untouchable type variables, and I *sort of* understand what’s going on here. If I add an extra argument to `f` that pushes the choice of `f` outside the inner `forall`, then the program typechecks:

```
f :: forall f a. f a -> (forall k. (F k ~ B f) => f k) -> A
f _ _ = undefined

g :: forall a. X a -> (forall k. (F k ~ B X) => X k) -> A
g = f
```

However, what specifically has me so confused in this particular example is why the functional dependency has different behavior. I have heard people claim at various times that functional dependencies like this one are equivalent to a type family plus an equality, but this demonstrates that isn’t actually true.

What information does the functional dependency provide in this case that allows `f` to be instantiated in a way that the type family does not?

Comment: Note that `g = f @ X` also type checks. It seems that the inference algorithm does not commit to choosing the type variable `f` as `X`. I can't see why -- usually, it's because there could be another value of `f` making the type `(forall k. (F k ~ B f) => f k) -> A` equal to `(forall k. (F k ~ B X) => X k) -> A`. Here, `f ~ X` seems to be the unique solution to me (isn't it?). Interesting.

Comment: @chi I think so, too, but I don’t know enough about this particular case of the typechecker to confidently open a bug. Perhaps I ought to open a ticket anyway, and if it’s intended behavior, I will at least probably learn why?

Comment: Interesting indeed! I've now twice cycled my opinion as to whether this should actually typecheck with _neither_ fundeps not type families, or only with fundeps, or with both. I just don't understand well enough how the constraints are resolved to decide. But at least I don't consider it implausible that only the fundep version should work: the crucial difference seems to be that typeclasses with their superclasses can be “unravelled” (the `f` be extracted out of `B f`), but from an equality constraint this is not possible.

Comment: Not an answer, but on your point "I have heard people claim that functional dependencies like this one are equivalent to a type family plus an equality" - yeah, it's a bit of an oversimplification. When you think about Core, you can see where the semantic differences come from. Type family instances are expressed as top-level coercions, so `type instance F Int = Bool` gets turned into `f_int :: F Int ~ Bool`. Fundeps just show up as constraints during unification, they don't affect coercions. That's why it's [hard to convert between them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43821747/1523776).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer either, but a beware: you haven't shown the FunDep version "allows `f` to be instantiated." Because you haven't declared any instances for `C` (and got `f` to work with them). Type family validation is more eager than for FunDeps. So you might have that actually the two forms are equivalent in the sense: the Type family form doesn't compile; the FunDep form has no inhabited instantiations for `f`. Perhaps that's why you can define only `f _ = undefined`. So declare an instance for `C`; try to apply `f` to something. Similarly try to apply `g`.

Comment: @AntC This is a reduction of a larger actual example where `C` is actually `Reifies` from `Data.Reflection`. I assure you, it really does typecheck without any bottoms anywhere *and* after applying `g`. You can even get this example to typecheck without bottoms yourself by changing `C` to `Reifies` and changing `f`’s definition to `f m = reify B (\(_ :: Proxy s) -> m @s `seq` A)` (after making `A` and `B` inhabited, of course).

Comment: to answer @chi's first comment: with `g = f`, yes that fixes the types s.t. `f ~ X`. If you take out the definition for `g`, then `f` can be any constructor type -- such as `Maybe`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I should post this as an answer because it's still pretty hand-wavey, but I do think this is what's essentially going on:

To evaluate a `(C k (B X)) => X k` value, you have to choose a concrete type for `k`, and point to the `instance C k (B X)` that fulfills the constraints. To do that, you must phrase out that the typeclass' `a` argument has the form `B f`, from which the compiler can extract the `f` type (and find out that it's `X` in this case) – importantly, it can do this *before actually looking at the instance*, which would be the point at which `f` would become untouchable.

To evaluate a `(F k ~ B X) => X k`, it's a bit different. Here you don't need to point to a concrete instance, you merely need to guarantee that *if the compiler looked up* the typefamily for `F k`, then this type would be the same type as `B X`. But before actually looking up the instance, the compiler cannot here infer that `F k` has the form `B f`, and hence also not use this to unify `f` with the outer quantification argument because of untouchable.

Therefore, GHC's behaviour is at least not completely unreasonable. I'm still not sure if it *should* behave this way.

Comment: While what you say makes some sense, I’m a little skeptical of this answer. Here’s why: if you change `data B` to `type family B`, the version with the functional dependency still typechecks! This seems like it would contradict your explanation for why the fundep version works the way it does, since `B f ~ B X` does not imply `f ~ X` if `B` is a type family.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've had a chance to play with this. There's several distractions:

In the Type Family version, just the definition for `f` gives error `'f0' is untouchable`. (You can suppress that with `AllowAmbiguousTypes`; that just postpones the error to appear against `g`.) Let's ignore `g` here on.

Then without `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, the error message for f gives more info:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘f0’ with ‘f’
    ‘f0’ is untouchable
      inside the constraints: F k ~ B f0
      bound by the type signature for:
                 f :: F k ~ B f0 => f0 k
  ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      f :: forall (f :: * -> *). (forall k. F k ~ B f => f k) -> A
  Expected type: f0 k
    Actual type: f k
```

Aha! a `rigid type variable` problem. I guess because `f` is fixed by the equality constraint from `k`, which is also rigid because ...

Turning to the `FunDep` version without `g`, at what types can we call `f`? Try

```
f (undefined undefined :: X a)           -- OK
f (undefined "string"  :: X String)      -- rejected
f  Nothing                               -- OK
f (Just 'c')                             -- rejected
```

The rejection message (for the `X String` example) is

```
• Couldn't match type ‘k’ with ‘String’
  ‘k’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a type expected by the context:
      forall k. C k (B X) => X k
  Expected type: X k
    Actual type: X String
• In the first argument of ‘f’, namely
    ‘(undefined "string" :: X String)’
```

Note the message is about `k`, *not* `f` which is determined from the FunDep -- or would be if we could find a suitable `k`.

**Explanation**

The signature for function `f` says `k` is existentially quantified/higher ranked. Then we can't allow any type information about `k` to escape into the surrounding context. We can't supply any (non-bottom) value for `k`, because its type would invade the `forall`.

Here's a simpler example:

```
f2 :: forall f. (forall k. f k) -> A
f2 _ = undefined

f2 Nothing                                 -- OK
f2 (Just 'c')                              -- rejected rigid type var
```

So that the original `FunDep` version compiles is a distraction: it can't be inhabited. (And that's a common symptom with `FunDep`s, as per my earlier suspicion.)

Comment: BTW you get a similar `f0 is untouchable` rejection with this signature `f :: forall f. (forall k. f ~ X => f k) -> A`. No Type Family or FunDep in sight.